# Privacy setting to enable online_presence?

Tags: facebook, api, permissions, facebook-fql

We're developing an application which need to get user's friends' online presence. I'm already getting everybody's presence but some of them returns null value. I googled it and some say that it's a privacy setting for each user.

I looked at my facebook test account's privacy settings and the only content is this:

Your status, photos, and posts
Bio and favorite quotations
Family and relationships
Photos and videos you're tagged in
Religious and political views
Birthday
Permission to comment on your posts
Places you check in to
Contact information

Everything is set to public for everybody but then I still its online_presence returns NULL value. Where can I find that setting to enable online_presence permission? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FQL, then the required permissions are `'user_online_presence', 'friends_online_presence'`. Alternatively, with XMPP, it is `'xmpp_login'`.